# help deriving Beta function as a ratio of Gamma functions

Tags: calculus, integration, gamma-function, beta-function

It comes directly from the [wikipedia page on the Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Gamma(x) \Gamma(y) &= \int_{u=0}^\infty e^{-u}u^{x-1} du \;\; \cdot \;\; \int_{v=0}^\infty e^{-v}v^{y-1} dv \\
&= \int_{v=0}^\infty \int_{u=0}^\infty e^{-u - v}u^{x-1} v^{y-1} dudv \\
\end{aligned}
$$

$u = zt$ and $v = z(1-t)$ means that $du = zdt$ and $dv = (1-t)dz$ I get the following after the substitution

$$
\begin{aligned}
&= \int_{z=0}^\infty \int_{t=0}^1 e^{-z}(zt)^{x-1} (z(1-t))^{y-1} z (1 - t) \; dtdz  \\
\end{aligned}
$$

But the Wikipdedia page has it as...

$$
= \int_{z=0}^\infty\int_{t=0}^1 e^{-z} (zt)^{x-1}(z(1-t))^{y-1}z\,dt \,dz
$$

So I must have gone wrong somewhere, but I cannot see my mistake. Can you find it? If I take the Wikipedia page as correct, I can get the rest of the way there, but I do not see why I am getting an extra $(1-t)$ after the substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $u = zt$ and $v = z(1-t)$ means that $du = zdt$ and $dv = (1-t)dz$

This is your error. For multivariable integrations, you need to use the Jacobian to change the variables.
$$
\begin{vmatrix} 
\dfrac{∂u}{∂t} & \dfrac{∂v}{∂t} \\
\dfrac{∂u}{∂z} & \dfrac{∂v}{∂z}  \\
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
z & -z\\
t & 1-t\\
\end{vmatrix}
=z
$$

Comment: thanks, this was driving me crazy. This leads me to another question though...After doing that, how is the bound for $t$ changed to $[0, 1]$?

Comment: The way to see that is to draw a picture of the u and v axis and mark z and t on that. $z=u+v$ so constant values of z correspond to diagonals. What does $t$ correspond to? Draw the picture and you'll see.

Comment: I've been trying to do what you said, but have failed so far. I guess I am confused about how I can mark $z$ and $t$ on a plane with the axes of $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Draw $u$ as $x$ axis and $v$ as $y$ axis then draw say $z=1$ on that, or $t=1/2$. If you can't work it out then ask another question.

Comment: Don't make any more comments is what I mean, if you ask another comment I will ignore it.